# Acoustic Echo Cancellation

Tags: android, aec

Does anybody know an AEC for Android that works with just one speaker?
Let's say I talk into my Android phone which streams the audio data to a PC which outputs these data immediately on speakers. So I will hear my own voice.

I am not sure if WebRTC- and Speex-AEC only cancel the echo of another speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not trying your situation, but in my case, i use the WebRTC-AECM module to deal with the echo things, and I did a loop back test on one android phone, it works good with no echos, but has lots of self-excitation when finishing speaking. hope i helped.

Comment: Thank you very much.
a) What do you mean with "self-excitation"?
b) Do you know if the cancellation works as well when there's a long delay? Let's say the voice comes out of the speakers one second later and not immediately. Would that still be all right?

Comment: a)I mean if I do the aec in a loop back situation, i can always hear screams when i finished speaking. b) 1s is too long to AECM module, the largest delay must less than 500ms, and if your delay is between 0ms to 500ms, all things will be alright.